# How can i send the JDBC Response from one thread group to another thread group Request in Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter-plugins

In Jmeter, i need to send the JDBC Response from one thread group to another thread group Request URL,
but without JDBC i can able to send the response from one thread to another thread,but if use the JDBC then 2nd Thread is failed. could you please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to provide comprehensive answer without seeing

- your Test Plan snapshot (Tools -> Generate Schematic View)
- what you are trying to send
- how you're going to use it in 2nd Thread Group
- [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file

Normally when you specify "Variable Names" and/or "Result Variable Name" in the [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler

[image]

it generates some [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which can be observed using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

for example:

given this database structure:

[image]

and the following JDBC Request sampler results:

[image]

if you define JDBC Results Variables like:

[image]

you will get the following variables created:

[image]

Once you see the JMeter Variable(s) you want to transfer to another Thread Group in the Debug Sampler it shouldn't be a problem to perform the transition using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) or [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)

Answer (score 0):

Set up your plan as below.
Add Loop Controller-->
Inside Loop Controller set your JDBC Connection Configuration and Request.
-->Add Counter(available in Config Element) and all other Request.
-->If you want to iterate it multiple time set your Loop Controller say 5
And make sure to keep you Counter with this setting [starting value=1;Increment=1;Maximum Value:1], It works for me.